# How to check current time is 12 noon in c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i need to check current time is 12 noon using c# and timer tick event is used to execute the code

```
            int secs = System.DateTime.Now.Second;
            int hours = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int minutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;
            string AmPm = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
            if (Convert.ToInt32("12") == hours && Convert.ToInt32("0") == minutes && Convert.ToInt32("0") == secs && AmPm.ToUpper().Trim() == "PM")
   {

}
else
{}
```

Comment: 1) Hour is in 24-hour format, so midnight=0, noon=12; 2) why `Convert.ToInt32("12")` instead of plain `12`?

Comment: Next problem: are you sure there is exactly one timer (not 0, not 2) tick inside that one second (12:00:00 - 12:00:01)?

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do:

```
var is_noon = (
    DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && 
    DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && 
    DateTime.Now.Second == 0
);
```

No need to convert strings to ints, you're using literal values anyhow.

However as Hans Kesting pointed out, depending on the `Timer` you're using there is a chance for inaccuracy so you'd want some leniency, personally, I'd drop checking for seconds.